# File not found while using a+

Tags: python, file-not-found

```
 if 'privnote.com' in message.content:
     if privnote_sniper == True:
         start = datetime.datetime.now()
         code = re.search('privnote.com/(.*)', message.content).group(1)
         link = 'https://privnote.com/' + code
         try:
             note_text = pn.read_note(link)
         except Exception as e:
             print(e)
         with open(f'Privnote/{code}.txt', 'a+') as data:
             print(f"\n{Fore.GREEN}{time} - Privnote Sniped" + Fore.RESET)
             elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
             elapsed = f'{elapsed.seconds}.{elapsed.microseconds}'
             PrivnoteInfo(elapsed, code)
             data.write(note_text)
             if notification:
                 toaster.show_toast("Sniper",
                                    "Privnote sniped! Look into console",
                                    icon_path="./drop.ico",
                                    duration=7)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\puffy\Desktop\PuffySB\main.py", line 497, in on_message
with open(f'Privnote/{code}.txt', 'a+') as data:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Privnote/0e77iYWk#6UEmMSGDn.txt'
```

Why does it say that there's no such file even though im using `a+`? shouldn't that create a file if it doesn't exist already

Comment: This can happen if the file you're trying to create already exists as a symbolic link to a file in a nonexisting directory.

Comment: A more likely problem is that the `Privnote` directory doesn't exist. `open()` will only create the file, it won't create the directory.

Comment: @Barmar - Looks like the user is on Windows, not Linux; see path in error **File "C:\Users\puffy\Desktop\PuffySB\main.py", line 497, in on_message**

Comment: If you are indeed on a Windows computer, you're mixing up forward and backslashes for your file paths. Try changing your _open_ call to this: **with open(f'Privnote\\{code}.txt', 'a+') as data:**

Comment: @LouieC Windows allows both forward and backslash and doesn't mind if you mix them.

Comment: @Barmar - well I'll be...! That's why I started doing this; to learn new things I didn't know!